# stop all htaccess rules for a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory for the CMS of a site and also a number of htaccess rules.
I was wondering how I get a rule to ignore a specific directory.

Here's an example of one of the rules I have, if you could give me the code to make this rule not apply to the directory `example.com/cms/` that would really help me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, I posted and answer but I deleted it because I'm not sure. Do you use more than just one domain? And only on one domain the /cms/ folder should be ignored?

Comment: well the cms will only be accessed by one person and it's a small project. So I think it will be okay if it can only be accessed through one domain. They only ever use that domain anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no rules in the cms directory, put a `.htaccess` file in the `cms` directory with the following:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```